# Extracting !URLCURRENT and editing it in imacros

Tags: firefox, imacros

I'm trying to create a macro that will extract the current url, edit it in the way described below and then be able to paste it in a new tab. I'm using Firefox 29.

For example:

I want to change this: http://url.com/a/b_c_XXXXXX_d.html
to this: http://url.com/a/b_c_YYYYYY_d.html
and then be able to paste it in a new tab.

Note: the macro only needs to be able to change "XXXXXX" to "YYYYYY", and there's no variation involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
macro +="URL GOTO=http://url.com/a/b_c_XXXXXX_d.html"+"\n";
macro +="ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}"+"\n";

var macro1;

macro1 ="CODE:";
macro1 +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
macro1 +="URL GOTO={{LINK}}"+"\n";


iimPlay(macro)

var link=iimGetLastExtract();

link=link.replace(/XXXXXX/,YYYYYY);

iimSet("LINK",link)
iimPlay(macro1)
```

Try this code and if there is an error let us know. The replace part is up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How can I integrate this code using imacros? Also, I'm not sure it will work because the "d" part of the url will vary through each iteration. All I want to do is extract the current URL, change XXXXXX to YYYYYY and paste it into a new tab. If it helps, XXXXXX=interaction and YYYYYY=view, always.

Comment: Place this into .js file. You need a little knowledge to finish thi script.

Comment: hello macroscripts. it seems that in line 5 of the code you've provided you forgot to enclose !URLCURRENT like {{!URLCURRENT}}. that's done now, and the rest of the code is perfect.

Comment: thank you very much. when you amend the slight error in line 5, i'll accept your answer. thanks again!

Comment: you forgot to enclose !URLCURRENT like {{!URLCURRENT}}. or at least upon changing that (for me) it worked.